# Out of date questions

Tags: discussion, good-questions, question-quality

So we have some questions that are now definitely out of date. The info is potentially still useful, but questions like the one about Cairo in January 2012, or London during the 2012 Olympics - definitely past their prime.

So, should we leave them open, or close them, or lock them, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "specific moment in time" reason for closing as too localized does not mean this. That would be if a question was something like "LAX to SFO airfares on 28th August 2012" - THAT is too localized.

I don't think there's any need for a witch hunt and go closing questions. Those questions are very obviously out-of-date. [Consensus on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92574/164542) seems to be to edit questions which are not "obviously" out-of-date and let them be.

Comment: I was more 'concerned' with people adding to them, not with deleting or anything - and wondered what the process was.  Looks like you've found the relevant MSO post tho.

Comment: The MSO post only seems concerned with SO though. Going out of date for SO really only means old versions, but they are still likely to be in use for years by some people. Our out of date questions about the previous Olympics can't really be used by anyone any more.

Answer (score 2):

Easy -- close as "too localized", but do not delete. There's nothing wrong with keeping these forever -- they are not bad for the site per se, just not very useful any longer. Also, all posters get to keep their reputation, and could repeatedly reap rep from them. No need to lock the question, AFAIR questions closed by mods cannot be reopened by the unwashed power user masses.

In this way, future visitors will still be able to get some useful information, if the event is recurrent, but at the same time, will be reminded that this question is possibly out of date and what is written may not be correct any longer.

Comment: I was also thinking "close but don't" delete... but then looking deeper I think I agree with Ankur. When we close we need a close reason and "too localized" should either apply or not apply - it shouldn't suddenly begin to apply after the date passes \-: